# window.addeventlistener('resize') componentDidMount loops in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

I have a small problem about window.addEventListener in componentDidMount. I have an API call there (axios).

```
componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.resize); //this one, i commented on my project to prevent DDoSing my server.

        fetch('my/api/path')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                
            });
```

Everytime I resize my screen, it loops the componentDidMount, making it like DDoSing my server. I have seen in Chrome's Developer Tools in Network Tab, yes, it makes a lot of request from my server as I resize my screen.

Comment: What are you doing inside `this.resize` ?

Comment: @DiwakarSingh resize() {
        this.setState({ smallSearch: window.innerWidth <= 760 });
    } to resize my search bar

Comment: Please confirm if have you bound `resize` with the component class `this` context in the `constructor`?

Comment: @DiwakarSingh I forgot to mention that If you mean like `this.resize = this.resize.bind(this)` and I already did that in a `constructor(props)`

Comment: At least the snippet that you have shared does not have the issue.

Comment: Did you ever remove the listener using `removeEventListener`?

Comment: @AjeetShah I didn't add that `removeEventListener` thing in my code. Is it the solution or answer

Comment: @aliamanuba You should have `removeEventListener` in your code. But I can't be sure that it is the reason of DDoD (too many requests) or not unless I see more component code.